# Is this initial condition a scalar or a vector?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $V : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a time-dependent vector
>   field, and let $x(t)$ be a solution of the differential
>   equation $\frac{d x}{d t} = V (x,t)$ satisfying the initial condition
>   $x(t_0) = x_0$.

Does it mean the initial condition $x_0$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or just a scalar?

$x$ is a vector-valued function, $x:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$. And if $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$, I guess we have
\begin{align}
x_1(t_0)&=x_{0_1}\\
x_2(t_0)&=x_{0_2}\\
&\vdots \\
x_n(t_0)&=x_{0_n}
\end{align}

But if $x_0$ is a scalar, $x_0\in\mathbb R$, I guess we have
\begin{align}
x_1(t_0)&=x_0\\
x_2(t_0)&=x_0\\
&\vdots \\
x_n(t_0)&=x_0
\end{align}

Which one is correct?

Comment: @Winther: Although it may be simple, that ought to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yeah you are right. I added it below

Comment: @Winther: Good. +1 from me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$x_0$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. You can see this from the fact that the domain of $V(x,t)$ is $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}$, so $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and note that $x_0 \equiv x(0)$. Your first guess is therefore the correct one: $$x_0 = (x_0^{(1)},x_0^{(2)},\cdots, x_0^{(n)})$$

Comment: So if I have $x(t_0)=x_0$ where $x:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ it is always true that $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$?